# Как выполнить подзапрос в ORM?

Tags: php, mysql, kohana, orm, kohana-3

Есть таблицы:

```
orders:
id, author_id, consumer_id, supplier_id, manager_id, status_id, created

orders_archive:
id, order_id, user_id, created
```

То есть, есть заказы, любой пользователь может отметить заказ архивным (заказчик, менеджер..)

Нужно получить все записи, которые создал текущий пользователь, и которые при этом добавлены/не добавлены в архив (этим же пользователем)

```
$orders = ORM::factory('Order')
->where('author_id', '=', $this->user->id)
->and_where(?)
```

Как вставить такой подзапрос? Я правильно понимаю, что нужно использовать DB::expr() ? Как?

Comment: а вы не пробовали для начала построить просто sql-запрос котрый-бы делал нужную выборку?

Comment: Ну в таком случае все просто: SELECT `orders` as `o` WHERE `o`.`author_id` = :user_id AND EXISTS (SELECT `orders_archive` as `oa` WHERE `o`.`author_id` = `oa`.`user_id`) - вернет все записи, которые создал текущий пользователь, при этом заказы были добавлены в архив их автором

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете сделать это так:

```
$orders = ORM::factory('Order')
    ->where('author_id', '=', $this->user->id)
    ->and_where(null, 'EXISTS', DB::expr('(SELECT orders_archive as oa WHERE o.author_id = oa.user_id)'))->find_all();
```

Но с точки зрения производительности это не очень хорошо, потому что создает подзапросы. Лучше написать raw sql query c join, а потом конвертировать полученную выборку в объекты модели:

```
$orders = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT * from orders where ...')->execute()->as_object('Order');
```